# Manipulating a class that derives from a List or Collection

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, collections

I am trying to make a List more user friendly by "incorporating" it into a new class, but accessing the List specific functionalities and properties from that new class is causing me trouble.

Here is an example:

```
public class Words : List<Word>
{
    public uint BytesPerWord { get; protected set; }

    public Word this[int index] => this.ElementAt(index);
  
    /*  public new Words GetRange(int index, int count)
    {
        var a = this.GetRange(index, count);

        return a;
    }*/

    public Words(uint bytesPerWord) : base()
    {
        BytesPerWord = bytesPerWord;
    }
}
```

Now, from elsewhere I try to extract part of someOtherWords of type "Words" into myWords by doing:

```
Words myWords = someOtherWords.GetRange((int)X, (int)Y);
```

Several problems here:

- GetRange is inaccessible. I have therefore tried to create a new version of it (commented out here above), but "this.GetRange()" creates a stackOverflow exception.
- Also "Word this[int index]" complains about hidden inherited members - But I guess it is related to the previous problem

Any suggestion on how to fix that would be very much appreciated.
Note that I have also tried to replace List by Collection as I have read I should not derive from a list, but it made no difference.

Comment: Why do you need to inherit `List<T>` and redefine `GetRange`? It's public method

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Words is just supposed to be more user friendly. Easier to refer to Words in my code base than always have to type List<Word> = new List<Word>(). I don't have to redefine GetRange, I just want to use it, but it does not work in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't be deriving from `List<T>`; it has a lot of behaviour that you probably don't want to inherit.

To avoid re-inventing the wheel, you can use `List<T>` through composition:

```
public class Words
{
    private readonly List<Word> _list; // Composition

    public uint BytesPerWord { get; protected set; }
    public Word this[int index] => _list[index];
  
    public Words GetRange(int index, int count)
    {
        var a = _list.GetRange(index, count);
        return new Words(BytesPerWord, a);
    }

    public Words(uint bytesPerWord) : this(bytesPerWord, new List<Word>()) { }

    private Words(uint bytesPerWord, List<Word> list)
    {
        BytesPerWord = bytesPerWord;
        _list = list;
    }
}
```

If you need your class to be enumerable, you can even implement `IEnumerable`:

```
public class Words : IEnumerable<Word>
{
    private readonly List<Word> _list;

    //...

    public IEnumerator<Word> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

The same applies to the other collection interfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in that case, I cannot do something of the sort: Words myWords = someOtherWords.GetRange((int)x, (int)y);

Comment: @stackMeUp No, it should be calling the private constructor, which is overloaded to accept a list.

Comment: Yes, did not work becasue of the typo :-) List<Words> should be List<Word>. I won't be able to do Words.Foreach() anymore though and have to implement some other interfaces.

Comment: @stackMeUp Sure you can: `public void ForEach (Action<Word> action) => _list.ForEach(action);`

Answer (score 2):

Your code cannot work because inside the method GetRange you call this.GetRange (not base.GetRange) and this creates an infinite loop until a stackoverflow exception occurs.

So you can change the code to

```
public class Words : List<Word>
{
    public uint BytesPerWord { get; protected set; }
    public new Word this[int index] => this.ElementAt(index);

    public new Words GetRange(int index, int count)
    {
        var a = base.GetRange(index, count);
        Words copy = new Words(100);
        copy.AddRange(a);
        return copy;
    }
```

However I am a bit perplexed how this will help the readability of your code. If you don't need to add any new functionality to a `List<T>` then I think it is not a good idea to hide the real nature of the variables.

Note also that this line:

```
public Word this[int index] => this.ElementAt(index);
```

could be written prepending the new modifier and optionally referencing the base class

```
public new Word this[int index] => base[index];
```

Another reason against the usefulness of this class.

Comment: That is very useful, thanks. It sounds like this idea of cleaning up is not such a good idea. So you would rather always expose the true name?  But then you always have to access List using "ElementAt()", which is more cumbersome than using brackets and is making the code less readable?   Edit: Sorry, it seems I can still use [ ]

Comment: Exactly, it is more important to give a meaningful name to your variables than defining a new type that does exactly the same things that a built-in type does. If someone needs to read your code it will be confused and probably will lose time trying to understand a difference that doesn't exist.

Comment: That is interesting as this was a concept originally introduced by my predecessor with 10+ years of C# experience and thought I was learning from the best :-( I started C# over a year ago, duh!

Comment: We are in the field of opinions of course and it is perfectly correct to create a new type that derives from a type already defined by the framework. But, for me, if you don't need to add something to the new type then you don't need to create a new type. For work I often have to do maintenance on old programs where this habit was quite widespread and invariably this thing irks me.

Comment: Hahaha, sounds like there is history behind this approach then :-)